# Recursive function only returns results of one branch of nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a branching nested dictionary to visualize species taxonomy data. I'm trying to write a function that gives me all the branches at a particular level.

I've tried iterative and recursive functions, but I have only gotten close using a recursive function. 
However, depending on where I put `return`/`print` statements, my function either returns `None` (but prints the correct information), or returns only one branch of the data. 
Using the second option, the output is perfect until the dataset branches.

```
tree = {"k-b":
        {"p-a":
         {"c-a":{"o-a":{}, "o-b":{}},
          "c-b":{"o-a":{}}},
         "p-b":
         {"c-a":{"o-a":{},"o-b":{}}}}}

def branches(tree, level):
    if level == 0:
        #print(tree.keys())
        return tree.keys()
    else:
        for i in tree.keys():
             return branches(tree[i], level-1)

print(branchNumber(tree, 2))
```

For level 2, I expect `[['c-a', 'c-b'], ['c-a']]` (it doesn't have to be an array of arrays, and I don't care if it has dict_keys() or anything else around it)

I actually get `dict_keys(['c-a', 'c-b'])`, which excludes the second branch

Alternatively, if I remove the 'return' before recursively calling branches, and uncomment the print statement, it prints:

```
dict_keys(['c-a', 'c-b'])
dict_keys(['c-a'])
```

Which is exactly the output I want, but the function returns `None` so I can't store that information for future applications

Comment: Your `return` inside the `for` loop, of course, only ever returns once, for the first item in the loop, so you never get to see the other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to return a list of all branches. One way to do this is with a list comprehension:

```
def branches(tree, level):
    if level == 0:
        #print(tree.keys())
        return tree.keys()
    else:
        return [branches(tree[i], level-1) for i in tree.keys()]
```

Note that this will return a deeply nested list. Flattening is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Are you sure you want to wrap a list around every level you descend in the tree? E.g. `branches(tree, 3) # => [[[dict_keys(['o-a', 'o-b']), dict_keys(['o-a'])], [dict_keys(['o-a', 'o-b'])]]]`

Answer (score 2):

Your code always returns the first item in the loop, so your algorithm ends prematurely and doesn't explore all the necessary branches. You could `yield` the results to create a generator function (among other approaches):

```
tree = {"k-b":
        {"p-a":
         {"c-a":{"o-a":{}, "o-b":{}},
          "c-b":{"o-a":{}}},
         "p-b":
         {"c-a":{"o-a":{},"o-b":{}}}}}

def branches(tree, level):
    if level == 0:
        yield list(tree.keys())
    elif level > 0:
        for v in tree.values():
            yield from branches(v, level - 1)

for i in range(4):
    print(f"level {i}:", list(branches(tree, i)))
```

Output:

```
level 0: [['k-b']]
level 1: [['p-a', 'p-b']]
level 2: [['c-a', 'c-b'], ['c-a']]
level 3: [['o-a', 'o-b'], ['o-a'], ['o-a', 'o-b']]
```

---

The line `elif level > 0:` is an optimization to avoid walking deeper into the tree than necessary.

Also, `for i in tree.keys()`, then `tree[i]` to access the value could be clearer as `for v in tree.values()`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to return a list of all items at that level:

```
tree = {"k-b":
        {"p-a":
         {"c-a":{"o-a":{}, "o-b":{}},
          "c-b":{"o-a":{}}},
         "p-b":
         {"c-a":{"o-a":{},"o-b":{}}}}}

def branches(tree, level):
    if level == 0:
        #print(tree.keys())
        return tree.keys()
    else:
        return [branches(tree[i], level-1) for i in tree.keys()]

print(branches(tree, 2))
```

Output:

```
[[dict_keys(['c-a', 'c-b']), dict_keys(['c-a'])]]
```